# Set character limit in ejs

Tags: javascript, character, ejs, limit

I am fetching content from JS in EJS template. I have a body field that contains more than 200 characters, but I want to show only 100 Characters in my view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can put up an if else condition like this in your EJS Template:

```html
<%if (yourField.length > 100) { %>
// Code to show 100 characters
<%= yourField.substring(0, 99) %>
<% } %>
<% else{ %>
//COde to print full value of your field
<%= yourField %>
<% } %>
```